# Why is Tesseract's .traineddata file not showing in heroku despite being uploaded and extracted succesfully?

Tags: python, heroku, file-upload, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to deploy an OCR app via heroku with Tesseract. `wget`ting the `.traineddata` files cause error, so I decided to compress them in a `.tar.gz` file and upload them in a custom buildpack from which the app builds. However, only the default `eng.traineddata` file is present, and the other `.traineddata` files are somehow getting deleted. The build log shows the files are extracted successfully. Pasting the build log below:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 183 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:        Using supported version of Python 3.6 (python-3.6.6)
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> detect app detected
remote: Unpacking Tesseract-OCR binaries
remote: ./
remote: ./bin/
remote: ./bin/tesseract
remote: ./share/
remote: ./share/tessdata/
remote: ./share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
remote: ./lib/
remote: ./lib/libtesseract.so.4
remote: ./lib/liblept.so.5
remote: ./lib/libpng12.so.0
remote: ./lib/libgif.so.7
remote: Getting Tesseract-OCR training data
remote: eng.traineddata
remote: ben.traineddata
remote: eng training data
remote: ben training data
remote: traineddata files loaded 
remote: ben.traineddata
remote: eng.traineddata
remote: Building runtime environment for Tesseract-OCR
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 73.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v24
remote:        https://brocr.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/brocr.git
   c7866b8..961e948  master -> master
```

Here is the output for `ls -as` command in the `$TESSDATA_PREFIX` directory:

```
~$ ls -as $TESSDATA_PREFIX
total 22928
    4 .      4 ..  22920 eng.traineddata
```

[Here is the compile script](https://pastebin.com/raw/MzwwmnGh) for the custom buildpack.
Am I missing something?